# Susy2 File to Import not found or unreadable, compiling with Compass via Gulp

Tags: ruby, bundler, gulp, compass, susy

Getting Compass and Susy to work together under Gulp - frustrating.

I can't seem to get Susy 2 working with gulp and compass unless I import the files manually (using the ["Manual Start"](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/#manual-start) directions from the Susy documentation).

*(I've asked once before, but wasn't able to find any relevant information... this is an ongoing issue for me across multiple development environments, so I'm asking again with as much background information as possible...)*

**Trying to import susy through compass using the [simple install](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/#simple-install) or bundler install fails for me every time, as follows:**

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'compass'
gem 'sass'
gem 'breakpoint'
gem 'susy'
```

### bundle install

and: bundle list

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * breakpoint (2.5.0)
  * bundler (1.7.2)
  * chunky_png (1.3.1)
  * compass (1.0.1)
  * compass-core (1.0.1)
  * compass-import-once (1.0.5)
  * ffi (1.9.3)
  * multi_json (1.10.1)
  * rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.5)
  * sass (3.4.3)
  * sassy-maps (0.4.0)
  * susy (2.1.3)
```

### config.rb

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require 'breakpoint'
require 'susy'
```

### Style.scss

```
@import 'susy';
```

Results In:

```
error sass/style.scss (Line 2: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
Load paths:
  ...

Compilation failed in 1 files.

  events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error:     error sass/style.scss (Line 2: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
Load paths:
    ...
```

Notably- the "Load Paths" seem to be missing the susy dir. For instance, I can see the path for other gems, such as breakpoint:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/breakpoint-2.5.0/stylesheets

Yet the "susy" gem path doesn't display there ("bundle show susy" points to:)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/susy-2.1.3

Am I doing something wrong or missing a step?

Comment: I've got susy working with that exact same bundle list. My 'bundle show' paths are a bit different though. The path is /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ and neither has /stylesheets after them.

Comment: I know right? I can't figure out what's going on. I've reinstalled ruby / compass / sass / bundler trying to get to the bottom of this, no luck though yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I doubt anyone else will ever encounter this situation, but just in case you do, I did eventually figure it all out.

It had absolutely nothing to do with my Sass / Gem config. It was entirely an ongoing system problem. The computer I'm working on has been part of a design studio for some time and has previously had all sorts of tools installed (beyond what I had set up myself). This included various versions of Ruby, CodeKit, Fire.App, etc on it. My problem was that there were all sorts of other gem paths defined. I'm not even referring to the shell path variable, or bundler specific paths, as I'm sure I had checked those settings as part of my troubleshooting.

When it finally came down to it, I removed all the old apps and cleaned up as much as I could find. I think it was specifically removing Fire.app that finally did the trick. When I went through and reinstalled the bundles again, things finally started to work. Hooray!